# Wireless dial up router

Tags: networking, router, wifi, dialup

Are there any inexpensive wireless routers (purchased preferably in UK) that share directly a dial up connection? I do not want an intermediate pc, just to plug the phone line on the router and be able go on-line with any wireless device.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a router that has a serial ports and an external modem, but in devices like the  [WiFlyer WDB20B](http://www.google.com/search?q=WDB20B) were made for that specific purpose.

Comment: Seems discontinued, any other router with a serial port and external modem?

Answer (score 1):

There's an Apple Airport Extreme basestation model which has an integrated modem.Works great with PCs too, though it's easier to do the initial configuration with a mac.  It can even do dial-on-demand if you're into that sort of thing.  A quick search of ebay.co.uk for 'Apple A1034' yields a couple results for around £20 shipped.